# JList Background Color

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I am creating a simple image browser. I am using a `JList` with wrapping:

`assetList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
assetList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);`

But I want to make the empty space dark. I tried sub-classing `JList` and having the `paintComponent` method change the background color, but it doesn't seem to work, it just keeps adding white to empty space.

[image: Image Browser]

Comment: Did you try [setting the JList's background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color))?

Comment: No, because that would be too easy and intuitive /s. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this :

private JList list = new JList(Model);
list.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

Comment: Sounds familiar :-D